# Mean value of mean value

Tags: probability, analysis, probability-theory

$\mu_X$ should be the mean value. 
Now I want to calculate $$ E[\mu_X^2] $$

My idea was the following: Since $\mu_X^2$ is a constant, I can write:

$$ E[\mu_X^2] = \mu_X^2 E[1] = \mu_X^2 \sum_{w \in \Omega} 1 \cdot P(\omega) = \mu_X^2 \sum_{w \in \Omega}  P(\omega) = \mu_X^2 $$

Is this right?

Comment: Mean of a constant random variable is the constant itself but you 'proof' is invalid for general $P$. It is valid only in the discrete case (i.e. when $P$ is purely atomic).

Comment: In the other case, I have: $ E[ \mu_X^2] =\int_{\mathbb{R}} \mu_X^2 f(x) dx =   \mu_X^2 \int_{\mathbb{R}}  f(x) dx=  \mu_X^2 $

Comment: The correct argument is: $E[\mu_X^{2}]=\int  \mu_X^{2} dP=\mu_X^{2}P(\Omega)=\mu_X^{2}$. There is no $f(x)$ involved here.

Comment: Thank you very much:)

Answer (score 0):

iF I understood it correctly (more context is always appreciated), $X$ is a random variable with mean $\mu_X \in \mathbb{R}$ (a constant)

Therefore, $\mu^2_X$ is also a constant, and so $\mathbb{E}[\mu^2_X]=\mu^2_X$

Think of a "random" variable that always takes the value $4$. What's its expectancy? Same logic applies to your case